# Literature on the differential operator $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-\frac{2\nu+1}{x}\frac{d}{dx} + x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I'm trying to find any possible literature on the differential operator $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-\frac{2\nu+1}{x}\frac{d}{dx} + x^2$. This is constructed out of the Fourier-Bessel differential operator and a harmonic piece. In the case that $2\nu+1=n-1$ is a natural number, this can be understood as the radial part of a Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^n$ plus a quadratic potential, i.e. a quantum harmonic oscillator in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is spherically symmetric. I've searched around for a while, but I've come up short. It may be that there is no literature outside of the case of $n=1,2,3$ (and $4$ here or there).

Comment: Is it possible that the first two term corresponds to the (radial part) Laplaceian in $\mathbb R^n$ with respect to $f(r) \delta_{ij}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the standard Euclidean metric?

Comment: @JohnMa This is a good question (and one I considered before) however it does not work out that way, unfortunately. The prefactor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}$ in the Laplace-Beltrami operator goofs that up big time.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w'' + \frac{2 \nu + 1}{x} w' - x^2 w = w'' + f(x) w' + g(x) w$ and suppose $x>0$. Taking the classic transformation
$$
w(x) = y(x)e^{-\frac{1}{2}\int f(x) dx} = x^{-\nu - \frac{1}{2}}y(x),
$$
the ODE becomes
$$
y'' - \left(\frac{x^4 + 4 \nu^2 - \frac{1}{4}}{x^2}\right)y = y'' - h(x) y = 0.
$$
For $x \ll 1$, using the WKB approximation, we have
$$
y(x) \doteq A h^{-1/4} e^{\int h^{1/2}} \sim x^{1/2}.
$$
This suggest that $w(x) = x^{-\nu} u(x)$ is an interesting transformation. With this in mind
$$
x^2 u''(x) + x u(x) - (x^4 + \nu^2) u(x) = 0.
$$
Finally, letting $z = \frac{x^2}{2}$,
$$
z^2 u'' + z u' - \left(z^2 + \frac{\nu^2}{4}\right)u = 0,
$$
so
$$
w(x) = A x^{-\nu} I_{\nu/2}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right) + B x^{-\nu} K_{\nu/2}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right).
$$

Comment: I wasn't looking for a way to solve it. I was looking for literature on it to see if people had ever considered it, i.e. if it's novel. If it had been used in a physical context, that kind of thing.

Comment: You said "any possible literature on the differential operator[...]". What if I had referred you to a Bessel functions book?

Comment: That would be fine. I mostly wanted an exposition on it, I suppose. It's pretty close to the usual quantum mechanical harmonic oscillator, but has the quirk of replacing $-\Delta$ with the Bessel differential operator. It seems like it would be an obvious candidate for study in terms of physics, but I came up short when searching around. If you have a reference, feel free to add it to your answer. Pending other answers, I'll gladly accept yours!

Comment: The operator $\frac{1}{r^\beta}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^\beta \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)$ has something to do with anomalous diffusion. I can't remember now, but I'll see what I can find.